# Rails delayed_job: update existing job instead of creating new one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, delayed-job

I'm using delayed_jobs gem to send a reminder notification to users phone an hour before his/hers reservation.

This works fine unless the user decides to change the start time of the reservation. When the user changes the star time, delayed_job creates a new entry.  This is undesirable behaviour because the user also gets a reminder for the initial start time which has been changed.

So what I want is to update the existing entry with the new start time or delete the first entry and create a new one.

I'm thinking of adding a new column to the delayed_jobs tabel for the reservation id and doing something like this:

```
 job = Delayed_jobs.where(:reservation_id => user.reservation.id)

If job.present? 
 job.reservation_id=user.reservation.id
 job.save
else
 # create new job
end
```

I'm not sure if this is safe because of the locks that delayed_jobs performs. Is it possible to check if there is a lock?

Also is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: I'd try not to create the job until you know it needs to be processed. Ideally, run a cron task every minute or 5 that would add the jobs then and process them immediately.

Comment: So basically go through all the reservations every 5 minutes and check the start time of each of them to determine if the use should get a reminder?

Comment: Yes - the more frequent the better.  Make it a high priority job so it never gets backed up.  If it's just sending emails, that could take 1 or two seconds, so it may get backed up if you have to send 1000s at 5pm or something.  Then you'd add more processes to flush the job queue.

Comment: The reminder is sent to users and is shown as a notification. At this point I think it might be a better option to sent to reminder immediately and plan it to be shown at the correct time on the phone. This way I don't have to constantly loop through all the reservations.

Answer (score 0):

You would only select reservations whose seating time is less than one hour from now, then create a job and send the reminder.

Add a :reminder_sent_at to the reservation so you can skip already reminded reservations.

Load the queue from the model so it's easy to call from a rake task and scheduler

```
class Reservation < ActiveRecord:Base

  def self.send_reminders
    reservations_to_remind = where(:reservations => {:seat_at => Time.now..1.hour.from_now}).where(:reminder_sent_at => nil) 
    potential_customers.each do |c|
      ReservationMailer.delay.reminder(c.id).send
    end
  end

  def reminder_sent?
    reminder_sent_at.present?
  end 

  def reminder_sent!
    update_attribute(:reminder_sent_at, Time.now)
  end 

end
```

Rake Task

```
namespace :reservations do

  desc "Send Reminders"
  task :send_reminders => [:environment] do |t|
    Reservation.send_reminders
  end

end
```

Then, in the mailer, check to make sure the reminder hasn't already been sent (due to race conditions, accidental reruns of the task, other mistakes, it could possibly be in the queue twice).

```
class ReservationMailer

  def reminder (reservation_id)
    @reservation = Reservation.find(reservation_id)
    unless @reservation.reminder_sent?
      mail
      @reservation.reminder_sent!
    end
  end

end
```